# Sequelize order by id for root table when we are using join method

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

this below `Sequelize` work fine for me without using `order`, i'm wondering why i can't use `order` for root table as `posts` model? when i use this below code i get this error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: 'posts' in order / group clause is not valid association
```

but that work fine on other models such as `channelVideoContainer`

```
   models.posts.findAll({
        where: {
            channelId: 1
        },
        include: [
            {
                model: models.channelVideoContainer,
                include: [models.fileServerSetting]
            }, {
                model: models.channelMusicContainer,
                include: [models.fileServerSetting]
            }, {
                model: models.channelImageWithTextContainer,
                include: [models.fileServerSetting]
            }, {
                model: models.channelFilesContainer,
                include: [models.fileServerSetting]
            },
            models.channelPlainTextContainer
        ], order: [
            [{model: models.posts}, 'id', 'DESC'],
        ], limit: 5
    }).then(function (result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    });
```

Comment: What field are you tring to order by? `id`? In that case I think it should be `order: ['posts.id', 'DESC']`

Comment: What is the Model relationship definition?

Comment: @miparnisari i get this error: ` ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'DESC' in 'order clause'`

Comment: @doublesharp post updated, please review that

Comment: @tux-world I misread your question, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are querying the `posts` table/model, and then sorting by a column on the `posts` model, however you are specifying a "joined" table in your `order`. This works for your other models because they are in fact joined (using the `include` option). Since you are querying the `posts` model you just need to pass in the name of the column you want to order by. See some of the [ORDER examples](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#ordering) in the documentation.

```
// just specify the 'id' column, 'post' is assumed because it is the queried Model
order: [['id', 'DESC']],
```

As a side note, you may want to specify `required: false` on your `include`'d models to perform a `LEFT JOIN` so that rows come back even if there are no matches in the joined table. If you know that rows will be returned (or they are actually required) then leave it as is.

```
{
  model: models.channelFilesContainer,
  include: [models.fileServerSetting],
  required: false, // LEFT JOIN the channelFilesContainer model
},
```